# How to split data in nlog.config?

Tags: nlog

I have 2 IPs like the below format in `aspnet-request-ip` field in nlog:

```
 1.2.3.4, 1.1.1.1:2000
```

but I just want to get `the first IP`. How can I do this?
The above IPs are fake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a big fan of RegEx, but here goes one solution:

```xml
${replace:inner=${aspnet-request-ip}:regex=true:searchFor=,.*:replaceWith=}
```

It scans for comma, and replaces the comma (and everything after the comma) with blank string.

- `"1.2.3.4, 1.1.1.1:2000"` becomes `"1.2.3.4"`
- `"1.2.3.4"` becomes `"1.2.3.4"`

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Replace-Layout-Renderer

Alternative one can also implement a [custom HttpContext Layout Renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer#aspnet-httpcontext)